# SQL Get distinct tax rate form a tax table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am optimistic that some clever SQL author can tweak my query to give the results I am looking for.  I have to extract the current tax rates for a state and distinct tax type (PST/QST/GST/HST)  There is usually PST/GST or HST per state.  Looking at the data table below I need to get the tax 'rate' for the distinct value of 'Shortname', 'name', and 'Effective Date'.

The desired result is this table:

```
EffectiveDate  Rate ShortName   name
2016-01-01  0.050000    AB  GST
2013-04-01  0.050000    BC  GST
2013-04-01  0.070000    BC  PST
2013-07-01  0.050000    MB  GST
2013-07-01  0.080000    MB  PST
2016-07-01  0.150000    NB  HST
2016-07-01  0.150000    NL  HST
2016-01-01  0.150000    NS  HST
2016-01-01  0.050000    NT  GST
2016-01-01  0.050000    NU  GST
2015-04-01  0.130000    ON  HST
2016-10-01  0.150000    PE  HST
2013-01-01  0.050000    QC  GST
2017-03-01  0.099750    QC  QST
2016-01-01  0.050000    SK  GST
2017-03-01  0.060000    SK  PST
2009-02-01  0.050000    YT  GST
```

My query so far:

```
    SELECT --TaxRates.ID, --TaxRates.StateId, TaxRateDetails.id, 
TaxRateDetails.EffectiveDate,  TaxRateDetails.Rate,--TaxRateDetails.TaxRateId,
States.ShortName,   TaxImpositionTypes.name -- DISTINCT Name,states.ShortName, TaxRateDetails.Id,TaxImpositionTypeDetailId 
FROM dbo.TaxRates
join dbo.TaxRateDetails ON TaxRateDetails.TaxRateId = TaxRates.Id
INNER JOIN States ON dbo.TaxRates.StateId = States.Id  AND States.IsActive =1
INNER JOIN TaxImpositionTypeDetails ON TaxRateDetails.TaxImpositionTypeDetailId = TaxImpositionTypeDetails.Id 
INNER JOIN TaxImpositionTypes ON dbo.TaxImpositionTypeDetails.TaxImpositionTypeId = TaxImpositionTypes.Id
WHERE  EffectiveDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
order BY ShortName
```

This source table created by this query is as follows:

```
EffectiveDate  Rate    ShortName    name
2016-01-01  0.050000    AB  GST
2009-02-01  0.050000    AB  GST
2013-04-01  0.050000    BC  GST
2013-04-01  0.070000    BC  PST
2013-04-01  0.050000    BC  GST
2013-04-01  0.070000    BC  PST
2013-07-01  0.050000    MB  GST
2013-07-01  0.080000    MB  PST
2010-07-01  0.130000    NB  HST
2016-07-01  0.150000    NB  HST
2010-07-01  0.130000    NB  HST
2009-02-01  13.000000   NL  HST
2016-07-01  0.150000    NL  HST
2010-07-01  0.130000    NL  HST
2016-01-01  0.150000    NS  HST
2010-07-01  0.150000    NS  HST
2016-01-01  0.050000    NT  GST
2009-02-01  0.050000    NT  GST
2016-01-01  0.050000    NU  GST
2009-02-01  0.050000    NU  GST
2010-07-01  0.130000    ON  HST
2009-02-01  0.050000    ON  HST
2009-02-01  0.080000    ON  PST
2010-03-01  0.130000    ON  HST
2015-04-01  0.130000    ON  HST
2015-04-01  0.000100    ON  PST
2009-02-01  13.000000   PE  HST
2013-04-01  0.140000    PE  HST
2016-10-01  0.150000    PE  HST
2013-01-01  0.050000    QC  GST
2013-01-01  0.010000    QC  QST
2012-01-01  0.050000    QC  GST
2012-01-01  0.095000    QC  QST
2017-03-01  0.099750    QC  QST
2016-01-01  0.050000    SK  GST
2016-01-01  0.050000    SK  PST
2009-02-01  0.050000    SK  GST
2009-02-01  0.050000    SK  PST
2017-03-01  0.060000    SK  PST
2009-02-01  0.050000    YT  GST
```

Comment: So you need the most rate for the most recent date of the unique shortname, name combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, we could assign a row number to each unique pairing of shortname and name order that pairing by effective date descending so the highest date is first.  Then we only display row 1 of each unique pairing of shortname and name .

```
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT TaxRateDetails.EffectiveDate
        , TaxRateDetails.Rate
        , States.ShortName
        , TaxImpositionTypes.name 
        , Row_number() over (partition by States.ShortName,TaxImpositionTypes.name ORDER BY TaxRateDetails.EffectiveDate DESC) RN
FROM dbo.TaxRates
INNER JOIN dbo.TaxRateDetails 
   ON TaxRateDetails.TaxRateId = TaxRates.Id
INNER JOIN States 
   ON dbo.TaxRates.StateId = States.Id  
  AND States.IsActive =1
INNER JOIN TaxImpositionTypeDetails 
   ON TaxRateDetails.TaxImpositionTypeDetailId = TaxImpositionTypeDetails.Id 
INNER JOIN TaxImpositionTypes 
   ON dbo.TaxImpositionTypeDetails.TaxImpositionTypeId = TaxImpositionTypes.Id
WHERE EffectiveDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

SELECT * FROM CTE where RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks!  that is awesome!!!  I didn't even know you could use 'With' in sql

Comment: Not all engines support it.  Current versions (and one or two back of each) of Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, and Postgresql all do but mySQL doesn't.  It could also be put as a subquery, but I like the CTE for readability and to show I din't really change your code, just added the row_number() line.  CTE = Common table expression you could alias it anything you want it to be... Like 'ACTIVE_TAX_RATES' if you wanted :P